# Three dimensional colour map in python

Tags: python, visualization, color-space

I would like to visualise a competition between three different processes in python. The figure should show the relative importance of each process at all grid points. My idea is to make a contourf plot with a colour map that has three extremes, for example red, green and blue. Every extreme would be assigned to one of the three processes and wherever several processes play a role we would see a mixture of the colours weighted by the relative importance of the processes. Does anyone have an idea if/how this is possible? Thank you very much!

Comment: I think the term you want to search for is "ternary plot", here are [some examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/701429/library-tool-for-drawing-ternary-triangle-plots).

Comment: It goes in this direction, but I would need to sort of plot the locations of the variables in the triangle as a colour mixture in my lat/lon grid. So for example at point (1,1) I have 60% A, 30% B and 10% C and it would be orange (mostly red, some green and a little bit of blue). And so on

Comment: Welcome to SO, merry! This question is likely to be closed as being too broad. Please ask a more specific question. You can edit and refine your question to clarify if you're looking for the geometric algorithms or how to measure the importance of your processes. It would also help to show us what you've done so far and where your approach fails. See the "help" link at the top of the page to learn what is on-topic and a good question for this site.